# Empty TextView after dragging item into another TextView?

Tags: java, android, drag

I have a number in a TextView and I'm trying to empty it as soon as the user drags and drops the TextView containing the number into a different TextView. I've tried this but it completely empties the TextView I'm dragging from and does not also show the number in the TextView I'm dragging to:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Toast.makeText(this, "here1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            // view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            firstTextView.setText("");
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `txt.setText(null);` ?, or I didn't understand the question

Comment: If i understand your question well. You want to do the following: You have textview1 and textview2. textview1 contains a number, textview2 is empty. You want to drag and drop textview1 into textview2, and as soon as you drop it, you want textview1 to become empty, and textview2 to have the number that was already in textview1. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. It's a bit tricky because I'm adding the number in TextView1 like this
firstTextView.setText(jsonRandNums.get(0).toString());